# Can i use aws loadbalancer to manage multiple glusterfs aws ec2-instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, glusterfs, elastic-load-balancer

For High Availability file system cluster, is it a good idea to use  amazon load balancer to manage the ec2-instances where i have setup the gluster cluster.

If i can use a aws load balancer is it possible to create a init script where i can specify the instance type,gluster installation steps in the load balancer. 
Thanks.

Comment: If you have multiple instance in the cluster you have to use a load balancer what other option do you have ?

Comment: Native glusterfs client has built-in fail over and high availability features. Also glusterfs has something called backupvolfile-server=server name
If this option is added while mounting fuse client, when the first volfile server fails, then the server specified in backupvolfile-server option is used as volfile server to mount the client.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a good idea.
Why don't you want to use [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) as your data storage?
It's redundant and highly available by design.

You can also set up [cross-region replication](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/crr.html) replication in order to have ultimate high-availability.

Comment: This is not the answer to the Question as User use case is using AWS ELB for Gluster fs and multiple instances?

Comment: I love S3, but it isn't like a normal filesystem. Stuff like appending to a log file simply isn't possible there, so it's not going to be suitable for plenty of situations.